# Assistance with .htaccess folder rewrite

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, uploader

I want to do an .htaccess rewrite for an image uploader I have on my site, but for all the tutorials I've tried, I can’t get it working.

Currently, the code I have uploads images to the folder:
`http://www.example.com/server/php/files/jkgh4f54.jpg`

I’d like to rewrite it so when you go to this URL: `http://www.example.com/jkgh4f54.jpg` it is showing the image from the above location.

Any thoughts?  As I mentioned, there are a lot of tutorials everywhere about stuff similar to this, but I haven't been able to adapt them to work thus far for me.

Current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$ /server/php/files/$0 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?code=$1 //For URL Shortener
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/site.com/404.php
```

Comment: sounds like you want to redirect, not rewrite. There are plenty questions on how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code, when the user visits `http://example.com/h3h2js.jpg`, they will see the image from `http://example.com/server/php/files/h3h2js.jpg`, but the URL in the browser will stay the same:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$ /server/php/files/$0 [L]
```

I have tested this code thoroughly on a clean installation of XAMPP on Windows. Image names **must** only contain alphanumeric characters of either case (a-z, A-Z, 0-9), and must end with a jpg, jpeg, png, gif or bmp file extension. If the requested image file already exists in the site root, the rewrite will not take place

Comment: Any reason this wouldn't work on a local copy (XAMPP)?  I don't have access to test this out unfortunately tonight on the actual domain but RewriteRule ^(.*).\(jpg|png|gif)$ http://localhost/site.com/server/php/files/$1.$2 is producing a Error 500.  (The http:// is in there too, but not able to get it to show in the comment at the moment).

Comment: Made it to the live environment and didn't work unfortunately.  http://www.example.com/jkgh4f54.jpg just passes to my 404 ErrorDocument handler.

Comment: I'll have a look at it (I haven't actually tested it yet). BTW, you can post code in comments as-is if you put it between backtics `

Comment: I've toiled away, and finally come up with a solution. See my updated answer for some lean, efficient code that you can use

Comment: First of all, this code is designed for use in a site root (such as `http://localhost` or `http://dragit.in`. I haven't tested it in a subdirectory. You are correct about it being `%{REQ` (I had to copy the code by hand); I've updated my answer

Comment: I worked it out using your method.  I had a couple of internal issues server side and as you said - the code was designed for the site root.  The final working code is in your answer above.  Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.jpg$ http://site.com/server/php/files/$1\.jpg [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work either in a live environment.

Comment: Ohh!  I feel like we are closer!  Your edit produced a redirect loop though: http://site.com/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/server/php/files/altatg6.jpg

Comment: Darn!  Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.  Same.

Comment: do you have a live version I can look at?

Comment: I will in a day or two, sorry for the delay I am actually in the process of rebuilding my web server from scratch.